Execute jdb commands from eclipse debugger
With eclipse CDT, you have the "debugger console" to execute gdb commands.
I want in a debugging session in eclipse to execute jdb commands.
Is there a way to achieve this goal ?
I parse almost every eclipse menus, but nothing that fits my need.

I think Eclipse uses JVM-TI or similar (maybe JDWP) and not jdb. Why would you want to execute jdb commands?

Do you have an example of such a command?

The main command I want to use is: redefine

I suppose with JVM-TI you have similar commands than jdb. If I can do it with another tool it is fine for me.

When Eclipse is attached or you've launched a Java application from it and recompiles your code, it automatically swaps in the new version of methods. You don't have to call redefine manually.

When you are in remote debug it does not work. I can rebuild the project under eclipse but it runs somewhere else (hence remote debug). When I update code of my tomcat server, it is not taken into account.

The problem was that the tomcat server restarts on changes, so the changes in debugging session were "undone".
There is a configuration option to set this.
